# Problema con el body del modal de bootstrap creado con el plugin bootstrap3-dialog de nakupanda

Tags: bootstrap, modal, bootstrap-3, diálogo

El problema es que el contenido no lo reconoce el `modal-body` y se reduce el tamaño del contenido a lo mínimo, edite la clase del `modal-body` a `panel-body` y se soluciona.

**Así se refleja el contenido:**
[image: contenido malo]

**Pero yo quisiera que en vez de `modal-body` sea `panel-body` para que se pueda ver así:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Como podría solucionarlo directamente con la librería?, claro si es posible.**

La [librería](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/#available-options) tiene una parte donde indica como manipular elementos del modal, pero no lo entiendo muy bien. Lo mas cercano que me pareció fue la parte donde dice ***Manipulating your dialog***.

**Acá el código que estoy usando:**

```js
var form = $('<form/>',{
  'class' : 'form-horizontal',
  'role'  : 'form'
});
var div = $('<div/>');
var label_nombre = $('<label/>',{
  'for' : 'filter_campo',
  'class' : 'control-label col-sm-2',
  'text'    : 'Código: '
});
label_nombre.appendTo(div);
var div_nombre = $('<div/>',{
  'class' : 'col-sm-10 col-xs-12',
});
var input_nombre = $('<input/>',{
  'type' : 'text',
  'class' : 'form-control',
  'id' : 'filter_campo',
  'name' : 'filter_campo',
});
input_nombre.appendTo(div_nombre);
div_nombre.appendTo(div);
div.appendTo(form);

var dialog = BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Agregar',
  message: function(dialogRef){
    return form;
  },
  cssClass: 'login-dialog',
  buttons: 
  [{
    label: 'Cancelar',
    action: function(dialogRef) {
      dialogRef.close();
    }
  },{
    label: 'Ok',
    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
    action: function(dialogRef){
      var fruit = dialogRef.getModalBody().find('input').val();
      if($.trim(fruit.toLowerCase()) !== '123456') {
        alert('Indique "123456"');
        return false;
      }else{
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

**Agrego:** si estoy creando los elementos mal y por ende no los reconoce el `modal-body` agradecería la instrucción de como debería hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione editando la clase

```
let content = dialogRef.getModalContent()[0];//obtengo el contenido del modal
let x = content.getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];//obtengo el div "modal-body"
x.setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');//y a continuación edito la clase
```

```js
let dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
  title: 'Agregar',
  message: function(dialogRef){
  
    let content = dialogRef.getModalContent()[0];
   let x = content.getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
    x.setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');
  
   let form = $('<form/>',{
      'id' : 'form_crear_item',
      'role'  : 'form'
    });
    let div = $('<div/>');
    let label_nombre = $('<label/>',{
      'for' : 'filter_campo',
      'class' : 'control-label col-sm-2',
      'text'    : 'Código: '
    });
    label_nombre.appendTo(div);
    let div_nombre = $('<div/>',{
      'class' : 'col-sm-10 col-xs-12',
    });
    let input_nombre = $('<input/>',{
      'type' : 'text',
      'class' : 'form-control',
      'id' : 'filter_campo',
      'name' : 'filter_campo',
    });
    input_nombre.appendTo(div_nombre);
    div_nombre.appendTo(div);
    div.appendTo(form);
    
    return form;
  },
  cssClass: 'login-dialog',
  buttons: 
  [{
    label: 'Cancelar',
    action: function(dialogRef) {
      dialogRef.close();
    }
  },{
    label: 'Ok',
    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
    action: function(dialogRef){
      var fruit = dialogRef.getModalBody().find('input').val();
      if($.trim(fruit.toLowerCase()) !== '123456') {
        alert('Indique "123456"');
        return false;
      }else{
        dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
  }]
});

dialog.open();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```